# python request is giving "Access Denied"

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I was trying to download some data using python request command as follows:

```
import requests

head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

session = requests.session()

session.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=fobhav&date=02-07-2011&section=FO', headers=head)
r= session.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2011/AUG/fo02AUG2011bhav.csv.zip', headers=head)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

But the above code is giving me following output:

```
403
b'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www1&#46;nseindia&#46;com&#47;content&#47;historical&#47;DERIVATIVES&#47;2011&#47;AUG&#47;fo02AUG2011bhav&#46;csv&#46;zip" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;661c2017&#46;1662218167&#46;332744f\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
```

Why am I getting "Access Denied"? If someone simply goes to the website, he can select the date and download the data.

**EDIT**

Site to visit to get the url: https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm

Select 'bhavcopy' and a date to get the link.

Comment: First, in the second request you should use the GET method instead of the POST (if you don't want to upload a file of course) . Second, 403 is probably normal behavior. When I visited this link [https][:]//www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2011/AUG/fo02AUG2011bhav.csv.zip, by browser I also received the 403 status.
Maybe you are authenticated when You visit this site by browser?

Comment: @JacekK Thanks for the reply. the link I've mentioned is generated when you visit the site : https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm

Comment: Ok, now I see. Interesting. 
Maybe you miss some important headers or cookies? Or maybe this is a cors policy. You can use some kind of proxy to capture browser requests, debug and compare it with your python code. If you are looking for good tools I recommended Burp suite or owasp ZAP. Or maybe selenium will be a better choice instead of the requests library?